# in Unix, how can I replace $ with \$$ in a string

Tags: unix, replace

I have a string in this format:

```
'abc pqr$v_val xyz'.
```

How can I replace `$` with `\$$`?  I want my final output to be:

```
'abc pqr\$$v_val xyz'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo 'abc pqr$v_val xyz' | sed 's/\$/\\\$\$/g'
```

eg:

```
user@host:/tmp$ echo 'abc pqr$v_val xyz' | sed 's/\$/\\\$\$/g'
abc pqr\$$v_val xyz
```

to assign variable;

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(echo 'abc pqr$v_val xyz' | sed 's/\$/\\\$\$/g')
#var=`echo 'abc pqr$v_val xyz' | sed 's/\$/\\\$\$/g'` # you can also use this

echo $var
```

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp$ ./test.sh
abc pqr\$$v_val xyz
```

Comment: and how can assign echo 'abc pqr$v_val xyz' | sed 's/\$/\\$$/g' toa variable

Comment: @user6615476 : I updated ans. I hope this can help you;

Comment: @Dez `$` is not a special character in the replacement, and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: @kdhp in Unix, using sed if you don't escape the $, it is taken as an anchor for the end of line.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206922/how-to-detect-end-of-line-with-sed

Comment: @Dez Only in a regular-expression, not the _replacement_ part of a substitute command.

Comment: @kdhp string after first slash delimeter of sed is a regular expression

Comment: @Dez The substitute command is described as `[2addr]s/BRE/replacement/flags`, furthermore the standard states that in the replacement "The meaning of an unescaped <backslash> immediately followed by any character other than '&', <backslash>, a digit, <newline>, or the delimiter character used for this command, is unspecified."

Answer (score 1):

```
input="a\$b"  #input is a$b

dollar="\$"
doubleDollar="\\\$\$"
output="${input/$dollar/$doubleDollar}"

echo $output #a\$$b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using perl, following code will just do fine .

```
$str1 = 'abc pqr$v_val xyz' ;
$str1 =~ s/\$/\\\$\$/g ;
```

In case you are using Shell and the value stored in a shell variable you can use the sed to same effect !

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't shown us where your input string is, I'll show two possibilities:

1. It's in a Bash variable (let's say `$foo`).  Then we can substitute as we expand:

   ```
   echo "${foo//$/'\$$'}"
   ```

   Note that we have to quote the replacement, so the shell doesn't substitute `$$` with the process ID.
2. It's input from a file or other stream.  Then we can use `sed` as a filter:

   ```
   sed -e 's/\$/\\$$/g'
   ```

   Here, we need to escape `$` in the pattern (because `$` matches end-of-line in a regexp) but not in the replacement.

---

Note: both of these replace all `$` from the input; if you only want to replace the first occurrence, you need to use `/` instead of `//` in the first example, or omit `g` from the second example.